# Using for loops with deleting elements from array

Tags: c#

Hi I'm creating a program that holds three arrays one for the persons last name, one for the points scored and one for the player number, now I've got all the arrays and everything done but when I try to delete a player it deletes the entire list instead of just the information of the player number entered. I am not sure on how to fix this.

Some guidance in the right direction would really help please and thank you

```
static void ProcessDelete(Int32[] playerNumbers, ref Int32 playerCount, String[] playerLastName, Int32[] playerPoints, Int32 playerIndex)
    {

        playerNumbers[playerIndex] = 0;
        playerLastName[playerIndex] = " ";
        playerPoints[playerIndex] = 0;

    }



    static void DeletePlayer(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastName, Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
    {
        int player;// Player number to delete
        int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
        if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
        {

            player = GetPositiveInteger("\nDelete Player: please enter the player's number");
            playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCount);


           if (playerindex != -1)
            {
                for (playerCount = playerindex; playerCount > 0; playerCount--)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastName[playerindex], playerPoints[playerindex]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Succesfully Deleted");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    ProcessDelete(playerNumbers, ref playerCount, playerLastName, playerPoints, playerindex);
                }
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: player not found");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: the roster is empty");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I think you'll have to reveal the ProcessDelete method where the problem probably sits and on the other side an array is not good for deleting. Consider some other collection like a List<int>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you revisit your design entirely:

- [Avoid multiple "parallel" collections](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/) like this. Instead, have a *single* collection of type `Player`, where `Player` is a new class consisting of a player number, a last name, and a score
- Use `List<T>` instead of arrays - the fact that arrays have a fixed size makes a lot of operations with them much harder. If you want to "delete an entry" you need to create a new array, and copy all the elements you still want from the old array into the new array. That's a pain. In your code you're not really deleting an element at all - you're just setting the score, name and number to default values. Using a `List<T>` you can actually remove the element.

Now your current code is also quite confusing here:

```
for (playerCount = playerindex; playerCount > 0; playerCount--)
{
    ...
    ProcessDelete(...);
}
```

Why are you looping at all? You've worked out the index you want to "delete" - so why aren't you just calling `ProcessDelete` once?

```
// Removed the playerCount parameter. Why is it there at all?
ProcessDelete(playerNumbers, playerLastName, playerPoints, playerindex);
```

Also, if `playerIndex` is 0, you won't loop at *all* - I suspect you meant the loop condition to be `playerCount >= 0` rather than `playerCount > 0`.

However, I can't see why the code you've presented would delete the information for more than one player - instead, it's deleting the information for one player multiple times. Either the code you've presented isn't your actual code, or you're not *actually* getting the result you think you are. (Or I've misread something, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll find it a lot easier if you put those three values into a class called PlayerDetails, then have a single list of that class.

There's a lot of things that don't make sense here.  Why do you only allow deletes if there are fewer than max players, for example?

It looks like you use the value -1 to indicate a non existent player. In that case, ProcessDelete should set to -1 instead of zero.

You have a for loop that says: Start at my delete index, go through each number to ZERO, delete that player. You don't need a for loop, just call ProcessDelete on your player index